# Starting ssh-agent from a script for use in multiple scripts (invoked by git)

Tags: bash, ssh, git, rsync, ssh-agent

I have some homepages in a git repository each. They are built by Jekyll. When I change something, I use git's `pre-push` hook to let Jekyll build the page and sync it with my HTTP server via rsync.

This makes is necessary to enter the password for my SSH key two times: One time for doing the push, and one time for the rsync run.

Now I tried to work around this by using ssh-agent and also by keychain. I tried to use something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]; then
    eval $(ssh-agent)
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
fi
```

in an own script and in git's `pre-commit` hook. The result is always the same: I'm asked for my key, but the agent seems to be fired up in an own shell – as soon as the script exits, the ssh key is locked again, and I have to enter the password again, both for the git push and for the rsync call.

So: Is it possible to start the ssh-agent (or keychain) in a way so that it can be used both for a git push and and pre-push hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables are only inherited "down" – the `eval $(ssh-agent)` has no way to make them persist outside of the /bin/bash process that's running this particular script. So if the SSH_AUTH_SOCK variable wasn't inherited from your shell by the 1st command, it won't be available for the 2nd one either.

For this reason, during local GUI logins the ssh-agent is typically started very early so that the entire GUI will inherit the environment. When working over SSH, you would have to use the `eval...` directly in your interactive shell so that SSH_AUTH_SOCK becomes available to all commands you run from it.

```
$ env | grep ^SSH_AU
$ ssh-add
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
$ eval $(ssh-agent)
$ env | grep ^SSH_AU
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-XXXXXXRM6v3r/agent.3047987
$ ssh-add
Enter passphrase for:
```

Doing so will cause useless ssh-agent processes to accumulate when you log out, so a better way to achieve the same thing is to run a nested shell using `ssh-agent bash` or `ssh-agent tmux` – ssh-agent will then exit whenever the command it ran exits.

```
$ echo "Shell PID=$$, socket=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
Shell PID=3047611, socket=
$ ssh-agent bash
$ echo "Shell PID=$$, socket=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
Shell PID=3047922, socket=/tmp/ssh-XXXXXXRM6v3r/agent.3047987
$
```

Another alternative is to replace "ssh-agent" within the eval with a wrapper script that stores the socket path somewhere (e.g. in ~/.ssh/agent) and when run a 2nd time directly returns the stored path, instead of starting ssh-agent again and again.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
agent_ok() { ssh-add -l > /dev/null 2>&1 || [ $? -eq 1 ]; }
if ! agent_ok; then
    if [ -e ~/.ssh/agent.info ]; then
       eval $(< ~/.ssh/agent.info)
    fi
fi
if ! agent_ok; then
    eval $(ssh-agent | tee ~/.ssh/agent.info)
fi
cat ~/.ssh/agent.info
```

ssh-agent can also be asked to listen on a specific path instead of a randomly-generated one, so that e.g. it could be started through a systemd user service:

```bash
if [ -S $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/agent.sock ]; then
    export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/agent.sock
else
    eval $(ssh-agent -a $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/agent.sock)
fi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very detailed answer!